delete all non matching keys from an yaml
I have an yaml like this
MyNodesList:
  - NodeName: test1
    status: active

  - NodeName: test2
    status: active
  
  - NodeName: test4
    status: active

  - NodeName: test5
    status: active

and I have a list of keys which has keys as test1,test5 I want to match these keys in yaml and delete all other dict where it is not a match i.e. I want an output
MyNodesList:
  - NodeName: test1
    status: active

  - NodeName: test5
    status: active

Can someone please help me here ?
................................................

Please explicate the technologies involved (programming language, environment, etc.). For example, using command-line tools like kislyuk/yq or itchyny/gojq or mikefarah/yq, this can be achieved using the filter .MyNodesList |= map(select(.NodeName == ("test1", "test5"))).

Thanks for your reply a python script may be sufficient which I can test on linux bash it would be great help if you provide a sample.
